# How to search for directories in Artifactory API?

Tags: artifactory

I know how to list files in a specific path but I want to get a list of all directories. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to use [AQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language).
For example, to find all folders in repo `myrepo` under the path `foo/bar/`, use the following query:

```
items.find({"repo":"myrepo","path":{"$match":"foo/bar/*"},"type":"folder"})
```